# Ejercicio en base datos Northwind

Tags: mysql

Por favor su ayuda con este ejercicio en MySql que no me esta realizando lo que le solicito, necesito listar código de producto, cantidad mínima, cantidad máxima, y cantidad total de productos vendidos de todas las órdenes en la tabla `Order Details`.

Muestre solo los registros cuya cantidad mínima sea 5 o más. Ordénelos por cantidad total en forma descendente.

Este es el query que estoy armando pero no me lista la información de forma correcta:

```
select ProductID, min(ProductID), max(ProductID), count(ProductID)
from orderdetails
group by ProductID
order by 4 desc
```

Comment: Seguro que es MySql o será MS Sql Server?

Comment: Si seguro es en MySql base de datos de prueba Northwind

Answer (score 1):

Te escribo la consulta en SQL Server, en MySQL puede que cambie algo en la sintaxis

```
select ProductID, MIN(OrderQty) cantidadMinima, MAX(OrderQty) cantidadMaxima, count(*) TotalProductos 
      FROM orderDetails
      group by ProductID
      having MIN(OrderQty) >= 5
      order by count(*) desc
```

El problema es que para filtrar que el mínimo sea mayor o igual a 5 se debe de hacer con having porque con la sentencia where no se puede. También te faltaba añadir el order by desc (descendente) para ordenar los campos.

Tu consulta no iba mal encaminada ;)

Comment: Mil gracias por el apoyo.